# is there any system function to get rgb from color name in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to get rgb array from color name, is there any system function to do this? or should I define a function like this?

```
function getRgbValue(colorName: string): string | null {
  const colors: { [key: string]: string } = {
    aliceblue: "240, 248, 255",
    antiquewhite: "250, 235, 215",
    aqua: "0, 255, 255"
    ......
  }
}
```

which way is a better practice?